# Understanding APIs as an Interface

Tags: interface

I've been doing a lot of reading on APIs, trying to understand all the interrelated concepts, and I would just like to confirm some notions about APIs.

- An API is an interface. So for example with the Windows API, this API is an interface between Windows OS and any program written for Windows which utilizes the Windows API.
- Now let's say that we're writing Program A in Java, and we want to access some Java library associated with the standard Java API. In this case, is the API an interface between Program A and the Java library?
- Finally, let's consider the Google Maps API. Is this an interface between Software A (mobile app, web application) which utilizes the Google Maps API and the Google Maps web mapping application?

Are these correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure; the "I" in API stands for interface, and it is between whatever wants to use the functionality being exposed and the code that provides that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, yes.  And the next step for recognizing or writing a good API is to understand what characterizes an interface.  I don't intend this to be an exhaustive list, but off the top of my head: an interface encapsulates (hides) the implementation as much as possible; and an interface makes guarantees about its behavior, in the form of documentation as well as language-specific features like what exceptions may be thrown.